# Php psalm configuration and syntax error reporting

Tags: php, psalm-php

I have a case with a simple syntax error.
It goes like this

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($a,$b,$c,) {...}
```

So, there is an syntax error after param $c -- an excess comma (im using php7.3).
When i run psalm
`./vendor/bin/psalm src/Foo.php --no-cache` it shows that nothing is broken here.

My question is am i missing some config or something else, why do psalm do not catch that simple syntax error case?

Comment: Maybe you should check this with the developer of Psalm

Comment: Psalm seems to be for static type analysis, not for syntax checking. PHP itself will detect that, as will any decent IDE.

Answer (score 1):

With php8 this code no longer brings errors:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($a,$b,$c,) {}
}
```

[Try it self.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3fff514c6a120379858321f8d0f8cdb13dd0dded)

I suspect psalm may already take that into account.

The decisive factor is which errors PHP itself delivers and not what any IDE or other tools display.

Answer (score 0):

Parse errors Psalm reports are generated by `nikic/php-parser` which Psalm uses under the hood, and the parser itself does not distinguish between PHP 8 and PHP 7 syntax.

The only reason Psalm reports parse errors at all is that it can't understand syntactically incorrect code. It's not Psalm's goal to find any syntax errors, there are a lot of tools that do that.

Thus you should be using a proper syntax checker, either `php -l` directly or some wrapper like [`php-parallel-lint/php-parallel-lint`](https://packagist.org/packages/php-parallel-lint/php-parallel-lint).